# See distance matrix in each step of hclust

Tags: r, hclust

How can see distance matrix in any step of the hierarchical clustering algorithm(use `hclust` function in `R`)?

Comment: Heavy lifting is done using Fortran code. Without hacking that part, you're out of luck with this particular function.

Comment: Will running `cophenetic` on the hclust object help you?